# Conversion from "datetime-local" to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, html, timestamp

I have a form with input of type "datetime-local" on a jsp page, the data is passed to a servlet:

```
String resetTimeString = request.getParameter(RequestParameterName.RESET_TIME);
```

How to convert the input to `java.sql.Timestamp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
Well, I found something new!

You can use `Timestamp.valueOf()` to format a time-string with the value of `yyyy-[m]m-[d]d hh:mm:ss[.f...]`
So it can also handle micro/nano seconds. The only thing you need to do is replace the **T** with a **space**.

This works:

```
String datetimeLocal = "1985-04-12T23:20:50.52";
System.out.println(Timestamp.valueOf(datetimeLocal.replace("T"," ")));
```

The output:

```
1985-04-12 23:20:50.52
```

---

According to [this site](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime-local.html) your **resetTimeString** looks like this: **'1985-04-12T23:20:50.52'** (a string)

I couldn't find a method to convert this to a timestamp directly, but you could just split it up manually:

```
String[] dateTime = datetimeLocal.split("T");
String[] date = dateTime[0].split("-");
String[] time = dateTime[1].split(":");
```

This will print:

```
System.out.println("DateTime: " + Arrays.toString(dateTime));
System.out.println("Date: " + Arrays.toString(date));
System.out.println("Time: " + Arrays.toString(time));

>>> DateTime: [1985-04-12, 23:20:50]
>>> Date: [1985, 04, 12]
>>> Time: [23, 20, 50]
```

After that you could just create a new Timestamp: (This is deprecated!)

```
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(Integer.valueOf(date[0]).intValue() - 1900, 
            Integer.valueOf(date[1]).intValue(), 
            Integer.valueOf(date[2]).intValue(), 
            Integer.valueOf(time[0]).intValue(), 
            Integer.valueOf(time[1]).intValue(), 
            Integer.valueOf(time[2].split("\\.")[0]).intValue(), 
            Integer.valueOf(time[2].split("\\.")[1]).intValue());
```

Note that, if you use this you need to subtract '1900' from the year and split dots with `\\.`

Also, you'd need to handle nanoseconds (In my example I'm using the value 50.52 as seconds, but the string returned from your server might not contain the nanoseconds)

You could also calculate a long from the date and use `new Timestamp(<long>)`

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I have hoped that there could be another, more convenient way to do it. But thank's anyway :)

Comment: Look at the top of my post ... I think that will help you better :)

Comment: The variant is really better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Cyphrags' answer won't work if seconds are set to `"00"`, because Chrome won't send the seconds part resulting in a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]` when calling `Timestamp.valueOf()`.

Therefore a more complete answer could be:

```
String datetimeLocal = "1985-04-12T23:20";
// make sure the seconds are set before parsing
if (StringUtils.countMatches(datetimelocal, ":") == 1) {
    datetimelocal += ":00";
}
Timestamp value = Timestamp.valueOf(datetimeLocal.replace("T", " "));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I took the liberty to remove your preamble because it could make someone feel that yours isn't an actual answer (therefore causing its deletion), while I think it is. Feel free to reject/edit differently